# Installing Superset Locally Using Docker Compose and Rancher Desktop on WIndows. Error: While importing 'superset.app', an ImportError was raised

Tags: apache-http-server, docker

I am following the superset docs https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose . But I keep getting this error over and over again.

superset_app           | Error: While importing 'superset.app', an ImportError was raised:
...
...